# Make a prototype of a braille tablet using arduino

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems

I want to basically make a pin matrix controller either by using spring, electromagnets or small motors. Spring being the most viable option. Something like what’s shown in the image. I'm pretty new to arduino and micro-controllers in general so any input would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to engineering SE. Good Question. I feel the it beneficial to add some additional detail. I found the following links [Braille Kindle' developed for the blind](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3399018/Braille-Kindle-developed-blind-Tactile-tablet-allow-people-feel-images-text-screen.html) and [Michigan Engineering seek solution to electronic braille](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3399018/Braille-Kindle-developed-blind-Tactile-tablet-allow-people-feel-images-text-screen.html#v-2259581232943615676). If these related I suggest that you include them in body.

Comment: Split it up. Ask a question for each part. I suggest: 1. Mechanics. 2. Electronics (everything between arduino and the mechanics) and 3: Arduino software. I suggest doing so in that order in this situation. Perhaps modify your question to ask for possible mechanical solutions